# Show last text message just above the text field using tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, textfield

I am trying to make a chat application using tableview and textfield in ios but i want the last send message seen just above the text field on tableview last row on click event of uibutton.
How to do this please help me.

```
-(IBAction)sendmessage:(id)sender
{
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSMutableDictionary *messageDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    NSArray *array = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *messageString = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *datallist =[messageString stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"message.plist"];

    if(messagearray == Nil)
    {
               messagearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
        NSInteger contactid = 0;
               if(datallist)
               {
                   BOOL isFileExist = [filemanager fileExistsAtPath:datallist];
                   if(isFileExist)
                   {
                       messagearray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:datallist];


                   }
               }
    if(messagearray.count >0)
    {
        NSDictionary *dic = [messagearray objectAtIndex:(messagearray.count - 1)];
        NSInteger val = [[dic objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
        contactid = val+1;
    }
    else{

        contactid = 1;
    }

    [messageDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:contactid] forKey:@"id"];
    [messageDictionary setObject:messageText.text forKey:@"id"];

    [messagearray addObject:messageDictionary];
    NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:messagearray format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];
    if(data)
    {
        [data writeToFile:datallist atomically:YES];

        [messagingtable reloadData];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error in save data: %@",error);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added response in array and reload table

```
[self.tblChatData reloadData];
```

you have to added indexpath when you scroll table

```
[self.tblChatData scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:arrContent.count-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` method of `UITableView`

> Scrolls through the table view until a row identified by index path is
>   at a particular location on the screen.

**Objective-c**

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
              atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
                      animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

**Swift**

```
func scrollToRowAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath,
       atScrollPosition scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition,
               animated animated: Bool)
```

**Parameters**

> `indexPath` An index path that identifies a row in the table view by
>   its row index and its section index.
>
> NSNotFound is a valid row index for scrolling to a section with zero
>   rows.
>
> `scrollPosition` A constant that identifies a relative position in
>   the table view (top, middle, bottom) for row when scrolling concludes.
>   See Table View Scroll Position for descriptions of valid constants.
>
> `animated`     YES if you want to animate the change in position; NO if
>   it should be immediate.

**Edited**

```
-(IBAction)sendmessage:(id)sender
{
    ...............
    if(data)
    {
        [data writeToFile:datallist atomically:YES];
        [messagingtable reloadData];
        // here, you need to scroll your table
        [messagingtable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: messagearray.count-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error in save data: %@",error);
    }
}
```

Reference  : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:

Comment: Where i use this method and what i write in this?

Comment: @AayushKatiyar Please check the edited section in answer. Hop this help to you!!